# How to generate Java keystore from X.509 Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore, truststore

I am trying to generate Java keystore from X.509 Certificate file, and don't know how. On other word, I want to convert  X.509  (application/pkix-cert) to java Keystore (application/x-java-keystore).
Do you have any idea how to do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For add the certificate to your keystore is this:

```
    keytool -importcert -keystore [keystore location, varies, but can be e.g.
 /etc/pki/java/cacerts] -storepass changeit -file /tmp/lb.cert -alias 
newSelfSignedKey -noprompt
```

Comment: @houchker It was a pleasure to help you :D!!